# Does training set's colour profile play role in Pattern Recognition with CNN?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I've recently started with Deep Learning and CNN which as quoted, attempts to extract the most optimal features from samples on it's own.
I made a model to recognize characters where the training set had images with black background and script in white.
[Image Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxsbJ.png)

This type of model though fails to recognize images with pattern in black on white background(I tried with my own input and the negative of previous set also).[Negative of Image Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DL9YS.png)

Is it possible to recognize both types of images using the same model or do I need to train two separate models?
I don't know if it's possible using ImageDataGenerator class.
Following is the current code snippet:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255, shear_range = 0.2, zoom_range = 0.2, horizontal_flip = True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
```

Comment: Try to use data augmentation to create negative version of light ones and vica versa. Remember that testset should also include negative examples, preferably naturally occurring ones.

Comment: @jonnor what's the point of "naturally" looking ones? why doesn't it count to invert existing images to their negative versions?

Comment: For training synthetic is fine. But the test set should match the real world data as much as possible. IF your inputs are images of real physical white on black text these will not be a perfect inverse of white samples. And if you have grayscale or color input won't be pure black or white at all. This *might* cause more misclassifications (or not)

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a situation ("negative images") where, as it was revealed relatively recently, the results are not what we may seem to expect them to be...

There is an unpublished paper @ ArXiv, which shows exactly that CNN models that have achieved almost perfect test accuracy at datasets like MNIST & CIFAR-10, fail to give similar performance in the respective "negative" images (i.e. with inverted background & foreground, like your case here):

[On the Limitation of Convolutional Neural Networks in Recognizing Negative Images](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.06857)

Here is the main result of the paper:

[image]

The issue is rather non-trivial, and there has been strong disagreement in the community as to if this result is indeed expected & unsurprising or not; see the (now archived) relevant discussion @ [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/60tex8/r170306857_deep_neural_networks_do_not_recognize/), as well as a relevant piece @ [KDNuggets](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/04/negative-results-images-flaw-deep-learning.html).

All in all, as the paper also suggests, you can do it with *one* model, but you will need to include at least some such "negative" images in your training. See also the SO thread [High training accuracy but low prediction performance for Tensorflow's official MNIST model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48839618/high-training-accuracy-but-low-prediction-performance-for-tensorflows-official).